# How to submit the antd form onconfirmation of antd PopConfirm?

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I have an antd Form on which i checked if entered date is past date then i show the Popup with antd PopConfirm and if user press 'Yes' in PopConfirm, i want to submit the form, how can i achieve this?

Below is my code :

```
<PopConfirm
              onConfirm={() => {
                
              }}
              cancelText={'No'}
              okText={'Yes'}
              disabled={!isPastDate}
              title={'Do you wish to continue with past date?'}
            >
              <Button type="primary" label="Save" htmlType="submit" />
            </PopConfirm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look like

```
                        <Popconfirm
                      placement='top'
                      title='Bạn có chắc chắn muốn lưu lại thông tin đã sửa?'
                      onConfirm={() => {
                        form.submit();
                      }}
                      okText='Ok'
                      cancelText='Hủy'
                    >
                      <Button
                        type='text'
                        style={{ color: '#004EBC', padding: '0px 8px' }}
                        htmlType='submit'
                      >
                        Lưu
                      </Button>
                    </Popconfirm>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// your component
(props) => {

  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  ...
  return (
     <Form
      layout='vertical'
      form={form}
      scrollToFirstError
      onFinish={onSubmitHandler}

      ... 

     // try removing the Button properties so it does not auto submit
   // in popup confirm
   onConfirm={() => {
      form.submit();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                            <Popconfirm
                                title='Are you sure to delete this task?'
                                onConfirm={() => {
                                    if ({ confirm }) {
                                        deletePetugas(petugas.id);
                                        message.success('Click on Yes');
                                    }
                                }}
                                onCancel={cancel}
                                type='primary'
                                okText='Yes'
                                cancelText='No'>
                                <Link to='#'>Delete</Link>
                            </Popconfirm>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button, Popconfirm } from 'antd';

const MyForm = () => {
    const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

    const [form] = Form.useForm();

    const handleFormSubmit = (values) => {
        console.log('Form submitted:', values);
    };

    const handleInputChange = () => {
        setShowPopup(true);
    };

    return (
        <Form form={form} onFinish={handleFormSubmit} onValuesChange={handleInputChange}>
            <Form.Item name='name' label='Name'>
                <Input />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item name='email' label='Email'>
                <Input />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item>
                {/* We use the Popconfirm component to display a confirmation dialog */}
                {/* We set the visible prop to showPopup to control whether the dialog is visible or not */}
                {/* We pass an arrow function to the onConfirm prop that submits the form */}
                {/* We pass a function to the onCancel prop that hides the dialog */}
                {/* We hide the Popconfirm button by setting its display style to "none" */}
                <Popconfirm
                    visible={showPopup}
                    onConfirm={() => {
                        form.submit();
                        setShowPopup(false);
                    }}
                    onCancel={() => {
                        setShowPopup(false);
                    }}
                    title='Are you sure you want to submit the form?'
                >
                    <Button style={{ display: 'none' }} />
                </Popconfirm>
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    );
};
```